# Urban Airship not creating a device token

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, urbanairship.com

How come I have no device tokens?

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary      *)launchOptions {

 //Create Airship options dictionary and add the required UIApplication launchOptions
 NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

// Call takeOff (which creates the UAirship singleton), passing in the launch options so the
// library can properly record when the app is launched from a push notification. This call is
// required.
//
// Populate AirshipConfig.plist with your app's info from https://go.urbanairship.com
[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

// Set the icon badge to zero on startup (optional)
[[UAPush shared] resetBadge];

// Register for remote notfications with the UA Library. This call is required.
[[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

// Handle any incoming incoming push notifications.
// This will invoke `handleBackgroundNotification` on your UAPushNotificationDelegate.
[[UAPush shared] handleNotification:[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
                   applicationState:application.applicationState];



  2013-03-19 04:22:44.202 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAPush applicationDidBecomeActive] [Line 555]        Checking registration status after foreground notification
  2013-03-19 04:22:44.204 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAPush applicationDidBecomeActive] [Line 561]           Checking registration on app foreground disabled on app initialization
  2013-03-19 04:22:44.241 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAUser listenForDeviceTokenReg] [Line 931]   ListenForDeviceTokenReg
  2013-03-19 04:22:44.270 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAUser userCreated:] [Line 467] User created:   201:{"username": null, "alias": null, "tags": [], "user_id": "xK4v5lARRDCAvekt25TeqA",   "user_url": "https://device-api.urbanairship.com/api/user/xK4v5lARRDCAvekt25TeqA/",   "device_tokens": [], "password": "oZeZFMO9SpyDZw3lM", "apids": [], "device_pins": [],  "ua_device_id": "2A6651E5-6D23-4FAD-B53C-4D6356D7A2AA"}
  2013-03-19 04:22:44.336 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAUser updateDefaultDeviceToken] [Line 978] Updating device token.
 2013-03-19 04:22:44.338 MyApp[1070:907] [D] -[UAUser updateDefaultDeviceToken] [Line 981] Skipping device token update: no token, already up to date, or user is being updated.
 2013-03-19 04:22:58.766 F
```

I have DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET & DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY in my AirshipConfig.plist as well as APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC = NO

Comment: looking at their code https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Common/UAUser.m there is a big 'if' statement there. See if you can figure out which one fails.. my guess is the token

Comment: I think problem must be in configured Urban Airshiup.Please follow link given by @Akbari Dipali again and follow all task again.

Answer (score 1):

I think, something is missing some steps while configuring:

please look at https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started:+iOS:+Push again

and try to log  you token in AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
[[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

also update the AirshipConfig.plist file

It can be issue of mis-configured certs / provisioning profiles.

Comment: I went through that tutorial which is how I got the above code. I have a breakpoint there and don't see any tokens. I'll add a log in to be extra sure. There are 0 tokens on the urban airship dashboard.

Comment: it's worth noting that "registerDeviceToken" is depreciated for me. I am using 1.3.0 of the library.  The other issue is that you can't call any methods on the library untill you have called takeOff first. If your using the provided surrogate then this will not work.  I am currently looking in to the best way of doing this. Will post here when I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Though you have DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET  & DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY, i guess UrbanAirship lib expects PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET and PRODUCTION_APP_KEY. When i added them in my AirshipConfig.plist, the issue got resolved and i was able to send push messages through UrbanAirship.